# Cannot find module from "undefined"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to import an external module inside my Sublime Text 3. The external module **Ship.ts** is a s follows:

```
export interface Ship {
    name: string;
    port: string;
    displacement: number;
}
```

The **output.ts** file contains **import Ship = require("./Ship");** and this file gets saved and built error-free. The **tsconfig.json** is as follows:

```
{
    "compileOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs"
    },
    "files": [
        "./Ship.ts"
    ]
}
```

However, when viewed inside and index php page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="node_modules/commonjs-require/commonjs-require.js"></script>
        <script src="output.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello TypeScript
    </body>
</html>
```

... there is a console error saying `commonjs-require.js:15 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./Ship" from "undefined"`. The .ts and .js files along with the tsconfig.json file are all in the same directory. Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Even if I change the contents of **Ship.ts** to:

```
export function greet(): void {
    console.log("Hello Ship");
}
```

... which transpiles to:

```
"use strict";
function greet() {
    console.log("Hello Ship");
}
exports.greet = greet;
```

... the error message `commonjs-require.js:15 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./Ship" from "undefined"` is unfortunately still on after trying to access it through either **import Ship = require("./Ship")** or **import {Ship} from "./Ship".**

**UPDATE**

Also tried to include `///<reference path="Ship.ts" />` or `///<reference path="./Ship.ts" />` at the top of **output.ts** but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the ./? I believe they are implied in this case.

Comment: What does this have to do with Sublime Text? Please don't tag your text editor unless the problem is specifically with it.

Comment: Alden. I tried a variety of combinations of removing the implied ./ but it did not solve the problem. The error message is still on.

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting an interface which doesn't generate any code, and you are trying to require it on runtime.

Comment: Stijn. Take a look at my update. The error is still on even if the contents of the file is a generated code.

Comment: Try `import {greet} from "./Ship" (maybe add the extension?) or add default to the function like`export default function`

Comment: I tried both suggested options. The -import- option has the same error. The second one (adding -default-) does not get through transpilation with an error saying _Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/typescript/Ship"' has no exported member 'greet'._